# WPF AutomationPeer.Initialize periodically throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, wcf

I have WCF service that runs WPF application to generate some screenshot.

In 95% of cases everything works fine.
But sometimes I get **TypeInitializeException** when I call **myWindow.Show** method.

The inner exception (**NullReferenceException**) occurred in static method **Initialize** of **AutomationPeer** class (PresentationCore.dll).

Full stack trace:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>
> Additional information: Инициализатор типа
>   "System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer" выдал исключение.
>   in
>   System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.RaiseFocusChangedEventHelper(IInputElement
>   newFocus)    in
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(DependencyObject
>   focus, Int32 timestamp)    in
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(DependencyObject focus,
>   Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)    in
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(IInputElement element)    in
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.OnSetFocus(IntPtr
>   hwnd)    in
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, WindowMessage message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
>   handled)    in
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    in
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    in
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    in
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    in
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)    in
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>
> ================= Inner Exception: [NullReferenceException]    in System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.Initialize()    in
>   System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer..cctor()

I have also found a workaround but it doesn't work: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpvsblog/archive/2015/03/19/automationpeer-initialize-nre.aspx. 
The same exception occurs in this line:

```
 WindowAutomationPeer peer = new WindowAutomationPeer(m_wnd);
```